# Working on a group in visual studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I am planning on working on a project with a group soon and i was wondering if there is a way in which we can work on it **at the same time** or any suggestion on how can i do this?

Comment: If you mean real-time editing of the same files collaboratively you might want to try dotnetfiddle.net

Comment: @OffDutyBlue i will try it, thanks for the reply!

Comment: You can use a version control system. There are different tools for that. For some you need a server, some are hosted in the cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS)

https://www.visualstudio.com/es/vso/

You can create a free account for small teams, and use git repositories and access to a lot of tools for manage projects, code, users, continuous integrations, continuos delivery and testing...

VSTS is better than TFS because is 100% online.

**Understand differences between VSTS and TFS**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/user-guide/about-vsts-tfs?view=vsts

**Features**

https://www.visualstudio.com/es/team-services/compare-features/

**QuickStart - User Guide**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/user-guide/?view=vsts

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stay with Microsoft, Use TFS

https://www.visualstudio.com/tfs/

A second popular option is using Git

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/gitquickstart?view=vsts&tabs=visual-studio

[image: TFS]

Comment: Thanks! Definitely have to give it a try.